# using statement for  SQL command

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, using-statement

I have for longer than I can remember not used using blocks when doing queries, however I now have an issue with locking tables and it looks like the queries are not disposing properley.

However I need to re-write the following code into a using block.

```
sql = conn.CreateCommand();
sql.CommandText = query;
sql.Parameters.Add("@p_DateFrom", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = datefrom.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
sql.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

int rowCount = (Int32)sql.ExecuteScalar();
sql.Parameters.Clear();
sql.Dispose();
return rowCount;
```

How would I go about re-writing this. Would I have to do the following:

```
int rowCount = 0;
using (sql = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    sql.CommandText = query;
    sql.Parameters.Add("@p_DateFrom", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = datefrom.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    sql.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    rowCount = (Int32)sql.ExecuteScalar();
}           
return rowCount;
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and see what happens? Then if you have problems you can come back and ask!

Comment: Locking tables hasn't really got much to do with `using` statements, especially since you are using `ExecuteScalar`

Comment: Disposing a command or connection has *nothing* to do with [locks on tables](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joesack/archive/2009/05/22/troubleshooting-table-locks.aspx).

Comment: @Tim well, not *quite* - if you have an open transaction on a connection (causing blocking) and close (dispose) the connection, it will release the locks.

Comment: Also: passing the datetime as a string is a big error.... you should pass it **as a datetime** instead.

Comment: @Nick because I can't test it in a test enviroment only live with no access to their sql server
I love how people have down voted the question its a valid question and the problem is the queries are causing suspended locks which I have never encountered and if the using blocks solve this then I'll re-write if not no point wasting time on it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't *have* to do it quite like that - you could use something like [dapper](http://nuget.org/packages/Dapper):

```
int rowCount = conn.Query<int>(query, new {p_DateFrom = datefrom}).Single();
```

job done; all disposed nicely, no messing with parameters, and it doesn't make the mistake of passing a datetime as a string (it should be passed as a datetime).

Answer (score 2):

> Would I have to do the following:

Yes.

**longer answer:**

Yes you have to do the following.

**Even longer:**

Yes you have to do the following:

```
int rowCount = 0;
using (sql = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    sql.CommandText = query;
    sql.Parameters.Add("@p_DateFrom", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = datefrom.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    sql.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    rowCount = (Int32)sql.ExecuteScalar();
}           
return rowCount;
```